# laravel 3 - (:any) route not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-3, laravel-routing

i am just starting to learn laravel. And found a small sample  project from nettuts+ ( url shortner ). it works well but only problem i face is that (:any) route doesn't  work.
Here are three routes i have in file.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});

Route::post('/', function()
{
    $url = Input::get('url');

    // Validate the url
    $v = Url::validate(array('url' => $url));
    if ( $v !== true ) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with_errors($v->errors);
    }

    // If the url is already in the table, return it
    $record = Url::where_url($url)->first();
    if ( $record ) {
        return View::make('home.result')
                ->with('shortened', $record->shortened);
    }

    // Otherwise, add a new row, and return the shortened url
    $row = Url::create(array(
        'url' => $url,
        'shortened' => Url::get_unique_short_url()
    ));

    // Create a results view, and present the short url to the user
    if ( $row ) {
        return View::make('home.result')->with('shortened', $row->shortened);
    }
});

Route::get('(:any)', function($shortened)
{
    // query the DB for the row with that short url
    $row = Url::where_shortened($shortened)->first();

    // if not found, redirect to home page
    if ( is_null($row) ) return Redirect::to('/');

    // Otherwise, fetch the URL, and redirect.
    return Redirect::to($row->url);
});
```

first two routes work fine but third one never gets activated. it only works if i call it with index.php in url. Like /index.php/abc whereas it should work for /abc too. And fyi, i have removed index.php setting from application config file too.

Can you please help ho to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the route declaration from `'(:any)'`

```
Route::get('(:any)', function($shortened){ //... });
```

to (`'/(:any)'`)

```
Route::get('/(:any)', function($shortened){ //... });
```